# How to fix "Code Clone Analysis - Error"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm unable to get *Analyze Solution for Code Clones* to work, it shows the following error:

[image]

The content of the *Output Window*:

```
An error occurred during the analysis.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: syntaxNodeOrToken
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.CSharp.CSharpParserUtility.SpanFromSyntaxNodeOrToken(SyntaxNodeOrToken syntaxNodeOrToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.CSharp.CSharpParserUtility.ToCodeCloneToken(SyntaxToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.CSharp.StatementWalkerBase.RecordStatement(IEnumerable`1 tokens)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxVisitor.VisitSwitchStatement(SwitchStatementSyntax node)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxWalker.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxWalker.DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxWalker.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.CSharp.StatementWalkerBase.Parse(SyntaxNode node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.CSharp.CSharpFunctionParser.ParseBody(BlockSyntax bodyNode, Function function)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.CSharp.CSharpFunctionParser.CompileParseFunction(SyntaxNode node, Function function)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.CSharp.CSharpFunctionParser.Parse(IFunctionIdentifier functionIdentifier, Boolean metadataOnly)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.Implementation.IndexUpdater.FullParseIndexFunctions(List`1 preParsedFunctions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.Implementation.IndexUpdater.BatchAddFunctions(IEnumerable`1 functions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.Implementation.SolutionIndexManager.AddAll()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.Implementation.SolutionIndexManager.DoUpdate()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.Implementation.CommonHelpers.Retry(Action action, Action actionOnRetry, Int32 count, ITelemetryScope telemetryScope)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.Implementation.SolutionIndexManager.UpdateIndex(EventHandler`1 progressCallback, ITelemetryScope telemetryScope)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeClone.Implementation.CloneAnalysisWorker.DoWork(Object argument)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Pretty hard to figure out the cause from that alone.

Tried to restart Visual Studio but that didn't fix anything.

Any clues are welcome.

Comment: What tool are you using for this analysis? It sounds like a bug there, not in your code. Does this tool have support and/or a bug tracker, where you can ask?

Comment: Your post motivated me to get it fixed by myself, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up debugging Visual Studio itself!

Turns out that a `switch` case with two conditions isn't supported:

```
switch (format, palette)
{
    case (TimFormat.Indexed4, not null):
        ToColorIndexed4(buffer, picture, stp, palette);
        break;
    case (TimFormat.Indexed8, not null):
        ToColorIndexed8(buffer, picture, stp, palette);
        break;
    case (TimFormat.Direct15, null):
        ToColorDirect15(buffer, picture, stp);
        break;
    case (TimFormat.Direct24, null):
        ToColorDirect24(buffer, picture);
        break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Changing it to this finally got it to work:

```
switch (format)
{
    case TimFormat.Indexed4:
        ToColorIndexed4(buffer, picture, stp, palette ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(palette)));
        break;
    case TimFormat.Indexed8:
        ToColorIndexed8(buffer, picture, stp, palette ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(palette)));
        break;
    case TimFormat.Direct15:
        ToColorDirect15(buffer, picture, stp);
        break;
    case TimFormat.Direct24:
        ToColorDirect24(buffer, picture);
        break;
    case TimFormat.Mixed:
    default:
        throw new NotSupportedException(format.ToString());
}
```

The general procedure was as follows:

- start a 2nd instance, disable `Debugging/Enable Just My Code`
- attach to 1st instance and start code clone analysis
- ignore few exceptions, at some point you'll reach the code clone analysis stuff
- roll back a few stack frames, you'll spot the text span where it choked
- edit your code to use a simpler syntax, rinse/repeat

Bug report for the fanatics:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Code-Clone-Analysis---Error-on-switch-/10600600